# MySQL keeps crashing on XAMPP in Windows

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb

(edit: I got it fixed by deleting all the master******.info files, as well as multi-master.info, mysql_error.log, and relay-bin files. My data got corrupted but basically I fixed it with [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/57157) solution)

I looked at other posts on stackoverflow and tried some stuff but they didn't work, and or they deal with errors different than the one I have. Every time I try starting up MySQL, I get the following output

"Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues. If you need more help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums"

This is the output in mysql_error.log file:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-11  3:52:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-11  3:52:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-11  3:52:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-11  3:52:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-11  3:52:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-11  3:52:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-07-11  3:52:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-11  3:52:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-11  3:52:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-11  3:52:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '\Users\Yousuf\Documents\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-11  3:52:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '\Users\Yousuf\Documents\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-11  3:52:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-11  3:52:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47215; transaction id 9
2020-07-11  3:52:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Users\Yousuf\Documents\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-11  3:52:33 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-11  3:52:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200711  3:52:33
2020-07-11  3:52:33 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

This is my my.ini file:

```
# Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# /Users/Yousuf/Documents/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is /Users/Yousuf/Documents/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "/Users/Yousuf/Documents/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "/Users/Yousuf/Documents/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "/Users/Yousuf/Documents/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "/Users/Yousuf/Documents/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "/Users/Yousuf/Documents/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = "/Users/Yousuf/Documents/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
#skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "/Users/Yousuf/Documents/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "/Users/Yousuf/Documents/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "/Users/Yousuf/Documents/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "/Users/Yousuf/Documents/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="/Users/Yousuf/Documents/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Neither changing the port (both in XAMPP settings and in the config file) nor commenting either line for bind listening ("Change here for bind listening"). Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Is that `my.cnf` file left over from the dark ages?  It seems to have `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M`  Change to 200M.

How much RAM do you have?  You may be able to go higher than 200M.

While you are at it, change `innodb_log_file_size` to `128M`.

Those were the default a decade ago (version 5.1?), but are not good today.

If possible compare the my.cnf in the new WAMP to the one you are using.  There may be other things I have forgotten about.